# dual GPUs? Both ATI and NVidia

Tags: drivers, gpu

I'd like to install both an NVidia GPU and an ATI GPU.  Since I'm using OpenCL, I need the proprietary drivers for each.  I've had troubles updrading to proprietary drivers and doing it successfully twice with all the potential conflicts worries me.  (i.e.- after a reboot, the GUI never initializes, necessitating a recovery or rebuild.)

Can it be done successfully?

Comment: I wasn't successful but i tried with legacy drivers. Would like to know too